# Preset Apache Superset Starter Plan, is it possible to embed a public dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

I am using Apache superset hosted by Preset, currently using the free starter Plan, is it possible to embed a dashboard in a public dashboard or we need to upgrade to other Plans

Comment: That's not a programming question and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding dashboards & charts for Preset Cloud is still in active development! Getting the security and compliance of this correctly is no small feat.

The Preset team is hoping to have a v1 in a few months, stay tuned!